# How to write python to open the another program

Tags: python

I'm the starter with python. The point is, I want to call program like calculator or terminal by write python code.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Your question seems to be not specific to the Raspberry Pi but is a general programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `os.system()` call.

Comment: Oh, sorry. My bad. (I'm actually blushing now, and I'm not kidding.) I just thought maybe a vote is better than a thank you comment, but it is not at all my place to say so. Sorry @bank.

Comment: Oh I don't think like that I understand your purpose.   :)